# Filtering all JSON strings given a value and printing in python

Tags: python

My code:

```
r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/players')

j = json.loads(r.text)["items"][0]["nickname"]
print(j)

player A

j = json.loads(r.text)["items"][1]["nickname"]

print(j)

player B
```

My JSON:

```
{
  "total_count": 2,
  "items": [
    {
      "nickname": "player A",
      "Game": "COD",
      "score": 1.0
    },
    {
      "nickname": "player B",
      "Game": "Tetris",
      "score": 1.1
    }
  ]
}
```

I wanted a way to print all "nickname". I tried a for but I do not know how to loop [0][1][3][4]..

For example:
for key in j:
    print(key, 'd', j[key])

Comment: You can instead loop over the json ``for x in json.loads(r.text)["items"]:x['nickname']``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `json.loads(r.text)["items"]` is a list and you can iterate over it.

```
j = json.loads(r.text)["items"]
for i in range(len(j)):
    print(j[i]["nickname"])
```

Alternately, as @Sushanth mentions in the comment, you can use a for each loop:

```
j = json.loads(r.text)["items"]
for i in j:    # iterates over j, assigning the values to i
    print(i["nickname"])
```

Comment: why does even a range required here, it should be simple for loop over the list ?